# Using ing verbs

Tags: grammar, spoken-english, learning, grammar-myths, error

How many times can you use ing without it becoming wrong?

> The waiting room was empty except for an old man **sitting** in a corner **reading** a book.

Is two times the limit?

> The waiting room was empty except for an old man sitting in a corner reading a book giving a vibe of indifference.

Is this correct?

How many ings can be stuffed in this sentence using connecting words like and, not, etc?
Please help

Comment: Who told you there's a limit?

Comment: Matters of style are largely subjective.  Some may have articulated a style guideline expressing a limit (@gotube) but if so that would not be a rule of grammar.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this, aside from it starting to seem silly at some point to tell the listener too many things.   It is correct use and grammar; there's no "limit".

Answer (score 11):

There is no limit in grammar. Three participles is not a problem at all.  Having very many such phrases would be annoying and poor style.

This is essentially a list, and there is no limit on how many items can be in a list:

> Go to the shops and buy apples, bananas, carrots, doughnuts and eggs.

> He sat in the corner eating an apple, peeling a banana, waving a carrot, stuffing a doughnut and cracking an egg.

Comment: I would say "bad style" or even"poor style"  rather than "bad English" because "bad English" could easily be taken to mean "incorrect English" (which is confusing right after you've said that there's no limit in grammar).

Comment: Repetition can also be poetic: "Sitting, sleeping, eating, working, going to school, striving, failing, crying and laughing -- these are all part of life."

Comment: @phoog I would say that I want to see a person do all that at the same time.

Comment: Repetition can also be done for fun, e.g. the nursery rhyme [The House That Jack Built](https://sites.pitt.edu/~dash/type2035.html)